# Passing an array name to a sub in VB.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I need your help for a problem I can't find any solution browsing the web.
I have few subs in a program, all of them are generating their own arrays.
Something like:

```
Private Sub SubName1()
   Array1(0,0) = 1
   Array1(0,1) = 2
End Sub

Private Sub SubName2()
   Array2(0,0) = 3
   Array2(0,1) = 4
End Sub

...
```

What I need to do next is to call another Sub passing the name of one of the pre-defined arrays. 
Something like:

```
...
If this = that then
    FinalSub(Array1)
Else
    FinalSub(Array2)
End if
...

Private Sub FinalSub(CalledArray() as string)
    DoSomethingWith(CalledArray(0,1)
End Sub
```

I cannot find how to do this... Any idea on how I can achieve this? (I hope I'm clear in my question) :)

Thanks a lot.
Vince.

Comment: Why does it have to be the name? If they are pre-defined then just pass a reference using `CalledArray(,) as string)`

Comment: How do you declare the Array1 and Array2?. You set them with a numeric value and then you try to pass them to a sub that expects an array of strings. Please use Option Strict On with VB.NET

Comment: Hi guys, fist of all thank you so much for the fast answers and comments. My app is doing query do SQL database and create one array per type of result, my arrays will be named based on the type of collected data. At the very end all the arrays are put into a PDF file but, to make the code lighter, I'm calling a sub that creates a table containing the datas so I need to call the sub creating the table passing few parameters like the number of columns and lines as well as the name of the array from which  data must be taken.

Comment: Forgot to mention that each Array is 2D but may have different lengths and contains strings. Here is how I declared them: Private Array1(12,1) as string; Private Array2(6,1) as string; Private Array3(8,1) as string; ... Of course mine are not called Arrayx, they have more explicit names :)

Comment: Seems like XY problem, If you show how your arrays created from result of sql queries  and what is expected data structure, I think you will get more suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Use `Dictionary(Of String, Integer(,))`

```
Dim myArrays = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer(,))()
myArrays.Add("Array1", New Integer(,) {{1, 2}}
myArrays.Add("Array2", New Integer(,) {{3, 4}}
```

Then use it

```
If this = that then
    FinalSub(myArrays("Array1"))
Else
    FinalSub(myArrays("Array2"))
End if
```

For this particular example you don't need names at all, because you can create an access arrays by their instances.

Comment: Hi Fabio, thanks for the solution. Can you have a look at my comment above to see if your solution can work? It explains why I need to pass the name of the array. (as you can probably imagine, I'm not an expert in coding :) Thanks you again.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of things, you are trying to pass the values within the array to a different Sub/Function. This can be done as easily as moving the declaration statement(s) of the arrays. Instead of declaring them within the Sub/Function, declare them as Class variables. If you declare them outside any Sub/Function, any Sub/Function within that class can use them and the variables they contain.

```
Public Class Test
    Dim array1 As Array
    Sub TestSub1()
        'can use array1'
    End Sub
    Sub TestSub2()
        'can use array1'
    End Sub
End Class
```

Versus

```
Public Class Test
    Sub TestSub1()
        Dim array1 As Array
        'can use array1'
    End Sub
    Sub TestSub2()
        'cannot use array1'
    End Sub
End Class
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/527aztek.aspx

Answer (score -1):

OK... I found an easy solution that could be called "the solution for dummies" LOL...

Instead of using 2D arrays, I'm using a 3D array and I used the first column to identify each of the original arrays.

Instead of

```
Array1(0,0) = 1
Array1(0,1) = 2
Array2(0,0) = 3
Array2(0,1) = 4
```

I'm using

```
My3dArray(1,0,0) = "Array1"
My3dArray(1,1,0) = "1"
My3dArray(1,1,1) = "2"
My3dArray(2,0,0) = "Array2"
My3dArray(2,1,0) = "3"
My3dArray(2,1,1) = "4"
```

So I Just have to call my sub specifying the first column ref.

```
FinalSub(1) ' to call the first set of values
FinalSub(2) ' To call the second set of values

Private sub FinalSub(id as integer)
    DoSomethingWith(My3dArray(ID,1,1))
End Sub
```

Probably not the best and most elegant way but it works :)

Thank you anyway for the answers and comments.

Regards,
 Vince.